# Adding An Image View to the Top of a Collection View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to add an imageView to the top of my `collectionView` programmatically (similar to a `tableViewHeaderView`) but so far, what I'm trying in `viewDidLoad` isn't quite working.

```
UIImageView *headerImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

if ([isHeaderVisible intValue]== YES) {

    NSLog(@"Header View was found.");

    [headerImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:headerImage]];
    [headerImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [headerImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 160)];
    [headerImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

}

else {

    NSLog(@"No Header view found.");
    [headerImageView setImage:nil];
    [headerImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
}
```

The logic of whether a header view is found or not is working, but I can't get the `UIImageView` to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. This isn't for a Section Header Title View, it's similar to the `headerView` found in Apple's App Store.

**UPDATE:**

I'm also using a section header in my `viewController`. So basically I'd like to use a section header and a view header. How would I be able to create a section header and a view header using the following:

```
 - (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
        DetailCollectionHeaderView *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        headerView.sectionTitle.text = collectionSectionTitle;
        headerView.backgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"WFSectionHeader.png"];

        reusableview = headerView;
    }

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter) {
        UICollectionReusableView *footerview = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"FooterView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        reusableview = footerview;
    }

    return reusableview;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the delegate methods of uicollectionview

```
-(UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView *view;

    if(kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader)
    {
        view = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"header" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        //_scroll.frame = view.frame;
        [view addSubview:_scroll];
         _scroll.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, _scroll.center.y);
        //_scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width * (MAXBANNER - 1),_scroll.frame.size.height);
    _scroll.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Hi Glenn! I was wondering about this though. Would this work if I'm already using viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind for my section header? In other words, would this work if I want a section header and a view header? PS I've updated my answer to show what I've done for my section header so far.

Comment: yes..just or better yet create a custom UICollectionReusableView subclass

Answer (score 0):

Working code. Try adding subView to reusableView. Direct setting imageView before assigning headerView to reusable use it does not accept.It will give error as:-
-[UICollectionReusableView setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa17be70

because there is not property like setImage in reusableView.So Prepare a view with image and add as subView to reusable View.
After assigning headerView to reusableView add imageView as subview to reusable view.

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

        [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionReusableView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView"];
        [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionReusableView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"FooterView"];
        [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    - (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;

        if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {

            UIView *headerView =[collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

            headerView.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];

            UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:headerView.frame];
            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-bg.png"]];


            reusableview = (UICollectionReusableView*)headerView;
            [reusableview addSubview:imageView];
        }

        if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter) {
            UICollectionReusableView *footerview = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"FooterView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

            reusableview = footerview;
        }

        return reusableview;
    }
```